# Windowed Application not opening in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Hi I am trying to learn java. I wrote a code which opens the string in window but actually it is not opening.

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class Test extends Frame {
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.drawString("Hello from Java",60,100);
    }


public static void main(String args[]){
    Test f = new Test();
    f.setSize(200,200);
    f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            System.exit(0);}});
}
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set it to be **visible**, using [`setVisible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29):

```
Test f = new Test();
f.setVisible(true);
// ...
```